# Use lists/dataframes as items in for-loops in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I am quite sure this is basic stuff, but I just can't find the answer by googling. So my problem:

I want to use a for-loop on a list of lists or data frames. But when you use list[i], you get all the values in the data frame instead of the data frame it self. Can anyone point out to me how to code this properly?

Example of the code:

```
a<-data.frame(seq(1:3),seq(3:1))
b<-data.frame(seq(1:3),seq(3:1))
l<-c(a,b)
```

Then l[1] returns:

```
> l[1]
$seq.1.3..
[1] 1 2 3
```

And I want it to just return: a

Comment: Use `[[` instead of `[`. `[` pulls sublists, `[[` pulls a specific element.

Comment: If you can post a sample of your data, or create your own data with input and expected output we can help you out a lot easier.

Comment: I think when you have `test[i-2]` you mean `test[j-2]`. You also have a problem that `test[1]` will be overwritten for every `i`. Maybe you mean to reaplce `test` with *"the matrix "a""*, which shows up in your text but not your code?

Comment: We can't really do any testing or debugging for you without reprodcuble data. We don't have `comb.rdata`, we can't create `dat` or any of your `subset`s or `wholeyear`, etc.  If you post a *small, reproducible example* of a little bit of data, (ideally copy/pasteable), we can help you much more easily. `dput()` is great for making data copy/pasteable. Just 2 subsets with 2 or 3 columns and 6 rows each is plenty to illustrate the problem and demonstrate a solution. It's also helpful if you can show the expected output for your small sample input.

Comment: Sorry about that, updated to be much easier to understand what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `list` function:

```
a<-data.frame(1:3,1:3)
b<-data.frame(3:1,3:1)

l<-list(a,b)
```

And access it's value with double brackets `[[`:

```
l[[1]]
l[[2]]
```

Ps: `seq(1:3)` and `seq(3:1)` outputs the same value, so I used `1:3` and `3:1`. :)

Comment: @Gregor When I use `str(c(mtcars, iris))` it gives me a list of vectors, not data.frames. Am I missing something? Thanks for the info!

Comment: Nope, my mistake. I just did `class(c(mtcars, iris))` and made a bad assumption. (Might be worth clarifying, `c(a, b)` is an *actual list*, but it's a list of all the columns from all the data frames. `list(a, b)` is what is wanted, a list of data frames.)

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for pointing about the actual list, I didn't know about that. I will update my answer. :)